# Vim switch y and z

Tags: keyboard, vim, keyboard-layout, german

Is there a way to teach vim to switch usage of y and z? So for example yy would save a file, ya would toggle etc.. This would be much more usable with my German keyboard layout.
What other technique could I use to cope with the problem of "dislocating" my fingers when using vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:noremap y z
:noremap z y
:noremap! y z
:noremap! z y
```

`:lnoremap` might be necessary instead of `:noremap!` ... See `:help :map` and `:help mapmode-l`.